# How to get a "Stream" with the GetAsync method of HttpClient in C# MVC?

Tags: c#, api, stream, smtp, getasync

I'm trying to get a "stream" object through an api, and then upload it to a message that will be sent by mail. The whole process WORKS, but the problem is when viewing the documents, because when I enter the inbox of any of the recipients, and try to preview or download and open them from any PDF reader, I get the following message :

> **There was an error loading the PDF document.**

I do not know if the loss of the content of the document is given at the time of making the request to the api or when I send the mail (which is by smtp, authenticated with oAuth2). Can someone help me? Below I show the key fragments of my source code:

```
App.Sell.Models.DocDTO.DocTypes docType = (App.Sell.Models.DocDTO.DocTypes)Session["AttachDocType"];
string docEntry = (string)Session["AttachDocEntry"];
string docNum = (string)Session["AttachDocNum"];

using (var cl = new HttpClient()) 
{
  //cl.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:xxxxx/");
  cl.BaseAddress = new Uri(ServiceRoute.cnString() + "MyWsOneSell/");
  cl.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
  cl.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
  var s = cl
    .GetAsync("api/PdfDocument/GetStreamDocument/" + c.DBName + "/" + docType + "/" + docEntry)
    .Result
    .Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;

    mailMessage.Attachments.Add(new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(s, docType + docNum + ".pdf", "application/pdf"));
}
```

And here is where I sent the email:

```
var mimeMessage = MimeKit.MimeMessage.CreateFromMailMessage(mailMessage);
using (var client = new SmtpClient())
{
  client.Connect("smtp.gmail.com", 587, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls); 
  var oauth2 = new SaslMechanismOAuth2(Email.From, Token.AccessToken);
  client.Authenticate(oauth2);

  try
  {
    client.Send(mimeMessage);
... rest of code. 
  }
  ...
```

Comment: `I do not know if the loss of the content of the document is given at the time of making the request` this is called debugging, you could easily send your self an email with a pdf using that code and check it. though the top code doesn't really look right anyway

Comment: Those 2 `.Result` calls make me so uneasy.

Comment: @JohanP yeah undefined behavior alert. though this is all a bit suspect